# At command : job number

Tags: shell, at-job

I'm writing a bash script where I use the command `at`.

How can I get the number of a job created with `at`? (In order to delete if needed.)

The command actually returns nothing. I get a response from the system when I use `at` in the shell, but I can't capture it. It's not coming from the command itself.

Comment: Please add some code you already tried. It will make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at `atq` after you've submitted your job?

Comment: Also a good idea to mention the operating system you're running.  `at` may be implemented in different ways in different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a Unix / Linux system. This answer was tested on a Solaris Unix machine.  Linux (Red Hat) is similar but the at job id format is a simple short number.

There's no actual `PID` produced until the job actually runs, but an `at job id` is returned to ***standard error***.

```
> at -t 07141116 2> at out < commandfile
> cat at.out
job 1436868960.a at Tue Jul 14 11:16:00 2015
```

You can check its status with the `at -l` command

```
> at -l
1436868960.a    Tue Jul 14 11:16:00 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

The job number is printed by the `at` command, but unfortunately it's printed to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), not to standard output. So to capture it you'll need to redirect it to standard output.

The following snippet captures the output of `at` into a variable. I run `at` in the C locale because it might produce different output in other languages. If the command failed, I print out the error message that I captured. Otherwise I parse the output to find the job number.

```
at_output=$(printf %s "$command" | LANGUAGE= LC_ALL=C at "$time" 2>&1)
at_status=$?
if [ "$at_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "at $time failed with status $at_status" >&2
  echo "$at_output"
  exit $at_status
fi
newline='
'
case "$at_output" in
  "job "*) at_job=${at_output#job };;
  *"${newline}job "*) at_job=${at_output#*"${newline}job "};;
  *) echo >&2 "$at_output"; echo >&2 "Unable to determine at job number!";;
esac
at_job=${at_job%% *}
```